# Error after upgrade of jest in NestJS project

Tags: javascript, jestjs, nestjs

guys!
I had a NestJS project where for unit-test is used `jest@29.4.*` after upgrade to `29.5.*` my test are failing with `Connot read proprietes of undefined '*request'`. I was looking for breaking changes and I dont found anything, If somebody find best solution for this issue please share :)
Thank you.

Comment: how did you import the 'request' package?

Comment: I mock this one, like this:
getRequest: jest.fn()

Comment: please show us some code or the stacktrace. The import line (nodejs import, not nestjs import) should be enough

Comment: After removing of mockRestore from jest options in package.json it works fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hey guys I find a solution, but idk if it is better one:
I used mockRestore, but when remove it. It works fine.